# rules of inference help

Tags: solution-verification

Let p, q, r, s and t be statements variables. Use the valid argument forms to deduce the conclusion, ¬q, from the premises, giving a reason for each step.

(a) ¬p ∨ q → r.

(b) s ∨ ¬q

(c) ¬t

(d) p → t

(e) ¬p∧r → ¬s

——————————————————

(f) ∴ ¬q

I have tried modus pollen on (c) and (d) but I can't find anyway to link to the other premise.

I have also tried double negation law and de morgan's law  on (e),  followed by hypothesis syllogism resulting in  p∨¬r → ¬q but it also got me to nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  You get $\neg p$ from modus tollens on (d).  Now (a) gives you $r$. Now that you have $\neg p$ and $r$ statement (e) gives $\neg s$.  (b) now forces $\neg q$.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by (a) gives r, do you mean I can use  ¬ from (c) and (d). Which rule did you use?

Comment: Since $\neg p$ is true, so is $\neg p \vee q$:  that's just the truth-definition of $\vee$.  Likewise, since $\neg p \vee q$ is true, so is $r$:  that's just the truth table for $\rightarrow$.  Etc.

Comment: oh now I get what you meant, thank you so much I didn't know you could see it like that when answering rules of inference qn